# SSIS Sql Server to Oracle datetime component

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, database-migration

We are migrating SQL Server system into Oracle implementation.

The application design date type:

- SQL Server is achieved with `DATETIME` datatype `EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_HIRED DATETIME)`. Some of the columns contains time component as well till seconds.
- Oracle is achieved with `DATE` datatype `EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_HIRED DATE)`. As we know, oracle date can hold time component as well

While migrating data from SQL Server to Oracle using SSIS, The system is defaulting it to `TIMESTAMP` datatype of oracle. Can this be defaulted to `DATE`?

There are around 1000+ such columns.

Do we need to address them manually through data conversion tool box? Can this be automated?

Comment: You are asking for a type conversion, not a default. Oracle's `DATE` has second precision while SQL Server's `DATETIME` has millisecond precision. You'd have to round or truncate one type to make it fit into the other. If you wanted SQL Server's columns to have second precision you should have used `datetime2(0)`. Perhaps you can change the source queries to cast to `datetime2(0)`

Comment: Is the package creating the tables and it's not the desired date datatype in Oracle or are they already defined and it's the metadata of the destination workflow step that's defaulting to the undesired datatype?

Comment: BTW what does `The system is defaulting` mean? SSIS uses the *target table types* in the destination, not any defaults. Did you try using SSIS to migrate the database schema? That's most definitely *not* its job. It's not a migration tool. It can't guess what the best type is for each product, generate indexes, constratints etc.

Comment: I have found that there is a difference between identified metadata of existing tables/columns when using OleDB & ODBC.  I think from memory we had better luck with OleDB.